# Using Config helper from within config file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

Is it possible to use the `config()` helper method within the 
`config/app.php` file its self??

I can't seem to get it to work. It just ignore it.

Example;

```
return [

    'extra' => 'test',

    'pages' => [
        'one',
        'two',
        'three',
        'demographics',
        'results',
        config('app.extra')
    ],

];
```

....from within the app.php file `config('app.extra')` does nothing.

Comment: Why you want to do this ?

Comment: i've put things in the config so it's quick to access. it's not the most elegant solution, I know that. but now I have duplicated code I'd like to cut down on. and I'm not going to write out loads of models/classes to tidy up the whole config just to address this one issue.

Answer (score 2):

Let's do a little experiment :D

Put three files in your config `a.php`, `b.php` and `c.php` and put these values:

a.php:

```
<?php
return ['name' => 'a'];
```

b.php

```
<?php
return [
  'name' => 'b', 
  'name_of_1' => config('a.name')
  'name_of_3' => config('c.name')
];
```

and c.php

```
<?php
return ['name' => 'c'];
```

Now from b.php you can access values of a.php but not of c.php

So...

```
dd(config(b.name))        //b
dd(config(b.name_of_1))   //a
dd(config(b.name_of_3))   //null
```

**Conclusion** You can only access values of previous config files from one config file. (And by previous it means alphabetically)